# Is Howard a psycho?

Tags: 10-cloverfield-lane

What does 10 Cloverfield Lane want to show to the audience?

I really don't understand the movie even though it was very interesting. Was Howard telling the truth or was he lying? Was he a psycho maniac? Does anyone care about explaining this for me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Both.**

[image]

Howard is a highly disturbed individual and it would appear he planned to  kidnap Michelle before the alien attack ever happened. There is also evidence that he kept her sedated for a period of time due to her nails having grown as evidenced by her nail-polish.

Howard wants a surrogate daughter and the alien invasion is incidental to his real motive.

[What Does The Ending Of 10 Cloverfield Lane Really Mean?](http://whatculture.com/film/what-does-the-ending-of-10-cloverfield-lane-really-mean)

> He is immediately protective of her when Emmett touches her, tells her
>   she will become a good cook like Megan and even dresses her in his
>   daughter's clothes. This may be why he kidnapped Michelle in the first
>   place; we see in the opening that he drives up behind her - could he
>   have ran her off the road while racing home to his bunker so he could
>   have a surrogate daughter for after the end of the world? I'd say it's
>   very likely; that crash isn't just from an accidental knock.

The article above discusses this abusive relationship and the coiled insanity of Howard in great detail and is certainly worth the read.

Comment: well... This makes me crystal clear now. Howard loses his daughter and wife and she replaces Emmett as his companion till the end of his life. Thanks for the explanation. :) @Dannie